# Import.io | Page loads only until i start recording authentication

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, import.io

i'm trying to scrape my first [website](http://supermercato24.it) using import.io. For some reason it loads the page properly until i start recording the authentication. As a matter of fact it hangs in the same way it would if it were running on a page with javascript disabled. The same thing happens even after having clicked 'Not Working' (That is supposed to activate js). Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You could try our (I work there) free support at support@import.io, i'd get in quickly though as import.io is killing off authenticated extractors soon. Here is why.

I don't know if any of the other services might work for you but there are plenty out there; outwit, diffbot, scraperwiki etc. Best of luck.

> We built the Authenticated API feature because lots of people
>   requested it, but it turns out less than 5% of users were able to
>   build one. Therefore, we have decided to remove the option to create
>   new Authenticated APIs on November 9th, 2015.
>
> **Why are we removing it?** To be honest, Authenticated APIs never worked as well as we wanted them to. They were too complicated to
>   build and nearly 80% of them never published. Which is probably why so
>   few of you ever tried to use them.
>
> Maintaining this bulky and minorly used feature is hindering our
>   ability to focus on other heavily requested features that would
>   benefit more users.
>
> Since our number one priority is to provide the best data extraction
>   experience for as many people as possible, we think removing the
>   ability to create new Authenticated APIs is the right thing to do.
>
> **What will happen to my existing Authenticated APIs?** They will keep working. You will be able to edit and maintain them, but you won't be
>   able to create new ones.
>
> We are planning to retire the feature completely mid-next year. We
>   will send more information when we have a firm date.
>
> **Will Authenticated APIs come back?** Maybe. We don't plan on rebuilding this feature as is, but we welcome your ideas and feature
>   suggestions.
>
> This is ultimately a strategy to do more for you. We want to keep the
>   dialogue open: if you have any concerns, comments or questions please
>   reply directly to this email.
>
> Thank you,
>
> The import.io team